# Does 1 Unbreaking II shovel last longer than 2 Unbreaking I shovels?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have just enchanted 2 shovels, both at low levels. They are both Unbreaking I.

Would I get more uses if I combine them into 1 Unbreaking II? Or should I leave them as 2 Unbreaking I shovels?

The Wiki was not much help - I was looking for a value that I can just compare.

Comment: Considering you can repair the tools, I think Unbreaking II would probably be better in the long run, because you can repair them with unenchanted shovels, but that's just my opinionated guess. I'm sure someone else can answer with actual facts.

Comment: @Chippies this should be taken into account in a good answer…

Comment: I recommend using one until it almost breaks and then use it to upgrade the second one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unbreaking causes tools to take durability damage only `100/(level+1)%` of the time. For Unbreaking I, tools take damage 50% of the time, so your effective durability is 2x. For Unbreaking II, tools take damage 33% of the time, so the effective durability is 3x.

2 Unbreaking I shovels would have an effective durability of 4x (since there's 2 of them at 2x each), wheras the Unbreaking II shovel you could combine them into is only 3x.

So, if you want to go for the hyperefficient analysis of the durability, yes, 2 Unbreaking I shovels will last a little longer overall than one Unbreaking II shovel.

Comment: Unbreaking III has an effective durability of 4x. You need to combine 2 unbreaking II shovels to get there, so 4 unbreaking I shovels.

Comment: No, because the unbreaking 1 shovels are more or less 2 unenchanted shovels, whereas an unbreaking 3 is 4 unenchanted shovels.

Answer (score 3):

If you use one of shovels almost to breaking point, then combine (puting used one in second slot of anvil), you'll get to use 5 unenchanted shovels worth of durability, for same cost in levels as combining before using; you could also use ~12% of the shovel that goes into first slot, but then combining would be also repairing and would cost a bit more, but you'll get ~5.24 shovels worth.

Comment: You are correct, I mixed up uses and durability in my calculation.

Answer (score 2):

The formulae for unbreaking is (100(level+1)) % chance for a use to use a durability.

So:

- an Unbreaking I shovel has a 50% chance that each use will not be free.
  (Lasts Twice as long)
- an Unbreaking II shovel has a 33% chance that each use will not be free.
  (Lasts Thrice as long)

Now this is all based of RNG so YMMV, but statistically speaking, each unbreaking I shovel (and you have TWO of them) is basically two shovels, and each unbreaking II shovel (and you WOULD have ONE of these) is basically 3 shovels.

2+2=4.

3=3.

Use two Unbreaking I.

[Formulae source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Unbreaking)